# How to label/track HOG detections in order to eliminate false positives?

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm working with hog svm in order to detect people in a video. 
I actually trained my own hog detector in order to have a flexible training and detection system. But my own hog detector have many false positives. A way to make it perform better is to eliminate the detections wich are present in isolated frames assuming that a person will not appear and disappear suddenly.

-Is there a way to label the hog detections in order to filter them?
   -Is it necessary in this case to track the detections ?
   -what is the best and fastest way to do it?

Comment: it is not an answer to your question but maybe you will test an [alternative approach](https://github.com/sturkmen72/C4-Real-time-pedestrian-detection) although it is not suitable to use commercially

Comment: thanks for your comment @sturkmen , I will check this out just for fun, it seems interesting. but for instance I have to carry on with my code and idea.